# C++ double pointers insert to linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I had an assignment recently that involved removing blocks of memory represented as a double pointer to a single page of memory.

Basically, I first have an array of `Page` pointers. Each `Page` has a `next_free` and `prev_free` field which both point to `Page*`. I'm trying to add a `Page*` page into a linked list of `Page*` pointers.

I'm going through the linked list where the `head` is pointed to by `pageArray[0]`. Iterate through this list of pages and insert the input `Page*` pointer in the right place according to its `value`.

```
struct Page {
    int value;
    Page* next_free;
    Page* prev_free;
};

Page* pageArray[10]

void insertPage(Page* page) {
    Page** currPage = &pageArray[0];
    while (*currPage) {
        double value = (*currPage) -> value;
        if (value < page -> value) {
            currPage = &(*currPage) -> next_free; 
        } else {
            break;
        } 
    }

    Page** prevPage = &(*currPage) -> prev_free;
    std::cout << "Value of current block: "
              << (*currPage)->value << std::endl;
    (*prevPage) -> next_free = page;
    std::cout << "Value of current block after changing previous block: "
              << (*currPage)->value << std::endl;
    (*currPage) -> prev_free = page;
}
```

I added print statements to see what happens, and it seems like when the `(*prevBlock) -> next_free = page` line is executed, the `(*currBlock)` pointers gets changed. I thought it would store the address of the previous block, and I can change `(*prevBlock)` without altering `(*currPage)`.

What is the right way of doing this? and why does `(*currBlock)` change?

Comment: i think you may need to rethink your algorithm, at start, you have an array of 10 nullptrs. when you insert a page, you will immediately have *currPage point to a nullptr but you carry on after the while loop assuming *currPage is not null.

Comment: In most cases the correct answer is `std::vector<T>`. If you are quite sure that a list is the correct data structure, then you should use `std::list<T>`. Implementing these standard data structures yourself should be avoided in C++ in any case!

Comment: This code is just to illustrate a concept. For example, if the array is null, I just insert the pointer to the page into the _free_areas array. Assuming there are pages, what is the correct way to manipulate the double pointers to insert the page in the correct order?

Comment: Please provide the main program that calls this function. How have you initialised the array? What is the value of `pageArray[0]->value`? What if you don't have a value yet? Will you call the function to insert the very first value?

Comment: Why mixing `int` and `double`? Why call members `next_free` when you deal with them as if they point to something that is **not** free?

Comment: *"...removing blocks of memory..."*: where to you remove blocks of memory? I don't understand the goal of the exercise.